# Implementation of strncpy

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc

I have tried implementing the **string n copy** function. I have succeeded in it but I tried to optimize my code which isn't working.

```
char *mystrncpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n)
{
   int i;
   char *temp;
   temp = dst;  
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      *dst++ = *src++;
   return temp;
}
```

The above code is working fine.

But the below one has some problems. It is just returning the `src` string for whatever `n` value I pass.

```
char *my_strncpy(char *dst, const char*src, size_t n)
{
   char *temp = dst;
   while ((*dst++ = *src++) && (--n));
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version doesn't work, because it might go one beyond `n`. Pull the test for `n == 0` in front

```
while (n-- && (*dst++ = *src++))
    ;
```

and don't put the `;` at the end of the line. It is easily missed there.

You can see a sample implementation at [`man strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

Answer (score 6):

These two fragments of code are not equivalent:

- the first one goes through and copies all `n` characters regardless of the content of the string;
- the second one stops right after copying the null terminator, or upon copying `n` characters, whichever comes first.

Neither first nor the second implementation is equivalent to `strncpy` from the standard library, which copies up to the terminator, and then continues on to fill the remaining space with zeros. To make your function standard-compliant, add this line before the `return` statement:

```
for (; n-- ; *dst++ = '\0');
```

Another thing to note is that the intent behind `strncpy` is often misunderstood: it is there to handle fixed-length strings, not variable-length strings with a fixed limit. That is why you need to null-terminate the results that you get from `strncpy`: if the `src` string is longer than `n` characters, the resultant string would not be null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, the simpler the better !

```
void Strncpy( char* _dst, const char* _src, size_t _n )
{
   size_t i = 0;
   while(i++ != _n && (*_dst++ = *_src++));
}
```